# How to fix 'subquery returns more than 1 row' with variable tables

Tags: mysql

I have a table `RAW_SCORES` that contains a bunch of homework/exam grades. There is a row in `RAW_SCORES` that contains the max points for each assignment.

```
('6410', 'Rivera',  'Rhonda',  '315', 64,  64, 28, 85,   98, 152),
('0001', 'MAX', 'POINTS',      '415', 100, 80, 32, 100, 120, 200),
```

I want to create a procedure that prints a table with the (Raw Score / Max Score) for each assignment. So for assignment 1:

```
SET hw1M = (SELECT HW1 FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE (SSN = '0001'));
SELECT RAW_SCORES.SSN,
    RAW_SCORES.FName,
    RAW_SCORES.LName,
    ROUND(RAW_SCORES.HW1 / hw1M, 2)
FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE NOT (RAW_SCORES.SSN = '0001' OR RAW_SCORES.SSN = '0002');
```

Gives me the correct result for HW1, but the table header says Round(bla bla bla) and the question wants it to be printed as HW1Pct. So I tried:

```
SET hw1M = (SELECT HW1 FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE (SSN = '0001'));
SET HW1Pct = (SELECT ROUND(RAW_SCORES.HW1 / hw1M, 2) FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE hw1M IN (SELECT HW1 FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE (SSN = '0001')));
SELECT RAW_SCORES.SSN,
    RAW_SCORES.FName,
    RAW_SCORES.LName,
    HW1Pct
FROM RAW_SCORES WHERE NOT (RAW_SCORES.SSN = '0001' OR RAW_SCORES.SSN = '0002');
```

But this gives me the `Subquery returns more than 1 row` error. Most of the other answers to this error are a `JOIN` statement, but I'm not sure how I would implement that in my case. Any help is appreciated. Sorry for it being a dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a column alias to your original query:

```
ROUND(RAW_SCORES.HW1 / hw1M, 2) AS HW1Pct
```

See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)